# Creating dynamically named textBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a new textbox every time I click a button. I see how it will work once, but not multiple times.

```
TextBox NewTB = new TextBox();
NewTB...// set textbox properties
this.Controls.Add(NewTB);
```

I need `NewTB` to be different everytime I click the button (NewTB1, NewTB2, etc), I tried a `List<>` that contained the names I wanted, then assigned the name as the `List<>` member, but that didn't work. Can I use some type of `List<>` that contains TextBoxes? I'm not really sure how to implement that.

Comment: `List<TextBox>` ... but it works multiple times because the *new* text box object is added as a control. It doesn't matter that the variable has the same name as it's called "a new" each button click event. That is, the controls collection itself will keep the TextBox alive (and accessible) while the `NewTB` variable will *hold* the result of `new TextBox()` (a *new* text box) that button click.

Comment: why not just an array of TextBoxes and use like `NewTB[i]`?

Comment: @Gajet Arrays are very arguably not grow-able :-)

Comment: @pst Can you give an example? I'm not really following you. Thanks!

Comment: @pst doesn't array have some function `resize`? see [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize).

Comment: @Gajet That creates a new array with a larger (or smaller) size and copies the data from the old array into the new array (and then assigns the new array to the same-named variable; that is why the first parameter is passed `ref`). It's easier just to `list.Add` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "NewTB" in your example is just a variable name. It is not assigned to that textbox in any way. The "list" of textboxes resides within the control structure. In other words, when you say `this.Controls.Add(NewTB)`, you are adding that textbox to the list of controls.

If the code that you show us happens as part of a click handler, it will be run each time the button is clicked, and therefore a new textbox will be added each time. `this.Controls` is essentially the List that keeps track of the controls (including textboxes) on your form.

Comment: Good start, but it doesn't end well when it switches to talking about postbacks -- this is WinForms not WebControls :P (a +1 because I suspect this will be updated and I liked where it was going ... at the start.)

Comment: @pst: Oops, missed the tag. :-P  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the ability to reference the textbox, you will need to you a list (which will give you the ability to create an indefinite number of them), and then add a reference to a new textbox the list every time you add the same reference to the control.  Every time you click the button, it should set your textbox to a new instance of textbox, and then add the reference of that instance to both the control and the list.

EXAMPLE:
To make the TextBoxen:

```
boolean iNeedMoreTextBoxes = true; //A simple boolean to be changed when you want
                                   //want to stop adding TextBoxes
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>(); //This makes a list of TextBoxes
TextBox tb = new TextBox(); //tb is nothing more than a pointer to the new TextBox
while(iNeedMoreTextBoxes){
   textBoxes.add(tb); //The pointer is added to the List
   control.add(tb); //The same pointer is added to the control
   tb = new TextBox(); //Make another TextBox
   iNeedMoreTextBoxes = checkToSeeIfINeedMoreTextBoxes();
}
```

Ok, so what that did was make a bunch of objects that and give a reference of each of those objects to the List and the control.  Now, whenever you use the List's reference to change the object, the control will change as well, because it has a reference to the same object.  Thus,
To retrieve the TextBoxen:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testBoxes.length(); i++){
   textBoxes.get(i).makeChanges(); //makeChanges isn't really a function, just an example
}
```

Now, if you need to be able to make a change to one specific TextBox, the TextBox class MUST have some identifying field, and then you would likely use this:

```
int id = getTheIDofTheTextBoxINeed(); //this can be any identifier that you can check
for(int i = 0; i < testBoxes.length(); i++){
  if(textBoxes.get(i).getID() == id) //Yay we found the right one, now make the changes
     textBoxes.get(i).makeChanges();
}
```

And that's more or less how you do it.

EDIT: This is java code, because I am not very familiar with C#.  However, I do know that underlying principles apply in both languages, just some of the syntax is different.

Comment: But if the List<> contains umltiple textboxes with the same name, once I add the control to the form, will it not replace it over and over?

Comment: The name doesn't really matter in that sense.  For instance, if you say: "TextBox a = new TextBox()" and then you say "myArrayList.add(a)" and then "a = new TextBox()", 'a' is now a completely different TextBox.  However, you still have a reference to the original 'a' by saying "myArrayList.get(0)".  You CANNOT retrieve the TextBox by saying "myArrayList.get(a)", because 'a' does not mean anything to an ArrayList.  I will edit my post to give you some example code.

Comment: Overall, this answer looks like it's on the right track, but the code examples look like Java, not C#.

Comment: Haha, I was editing to explain that while you posted your comment.